# pandas remove seconds from datetime index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, seconds

I have a pandas dataFrame called 'df' as follows

```
                       value    
2015-09-27 03:58:30    1.0  
2015-09-27 03:59:30    1.0  
2015-09-27 04:00:30    1.0  
2015-09-27 04:01:30    1.0
```

I just want to strip out the seconds to get this

```
                       value    
2015-09-27 03:58:00    1.0  
2015-09-27 03:59:00    1.0  
2015-09-27 04:00:00    1.0  
2015-09-27 04:01:00    1.0
```

How can i do this?

ive tried things like

```
df.index.to_series().apply(datetime.replace(second=0, microsecond=0))
```

but i always get errors

```
TypeError: descriptor 'replace' of 'datetime.datetime' object needs an argument
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could use [`datetime.replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.replace) to alter the second's attribute as shown:

```
df.index = df.index.map(lambda x: x.replace(second=0))
```

[image]

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.round.html looks better, learned from https://stackoverflow.com/a/43400370/856804